# Int64Dtype breaks query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given this dataframe and code

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame([4711], columns=['A'])
print(df.info())
print(df[df.A == 4711])
print(df.query('A == 4711'))
```

The output is the same for the two query types, as expected, and the data type int64.

But when the data type is changed

```
df.A = df.A.astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
print(df.info())
print(df[df.A == 4711])
print(df.query('A == 4711'))
```

the last query results in

> ValueError: unknown type object

Why would this not work as before? Thanks for any insights!

In case it helps here is the output of

```
pd.show_versions(as_json=False)

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.7.3.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 10
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None
LOCALE: None.None

pandas: 0.24.2
pytest: 4.3.1
pip: 19.0.3
setuptools: 40.8.0
Cython: 0.29.6
numpy: 1.16.2
scipy: 1.2.1
pyarrow: None
xarray: None
IPython: 7.4.0
sphinx: 1.8.5
patsy: 0.5.1
dateutil: 2.8.0
pytz: 2018.9
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.2.1
tables: 3.5.1
numexpr: 2.6.9
feather: None
matplotlib: 3.0.3
openpyxl: 2.6.1
xlrd: 1.2.0
xlwt: 1.3.0
xlsxwriter: 1.1.5
lxml.etree: 4.3.2
bs4: 4.7.1
html5lib: 1.0.1
sqlalchemy: 1.3.1
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: 2.10
s3fs: None
fastparquet: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: None
gcsfs: None
```

Comment: This problem is not in `pandas==0.25.0`.

Comment: Sorry to say it still appears after upgrading.

Comment: could not replicate in pandas 0.25.3

Comment: note also that IntegerArray, which Int64Dtype is part of, is currently experimental. see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#nullable-integer-data-type